# how set yesterday date as default in Extjs datePicker

Tags: extjs

```
{
                title: 'Start Date',
                margin: '0 20 0 0',
                items:{
                    xtype: 'datepicker',
                    fieldLabel: 'START DATE',
                    value: new Date(),
                    itemId: 'startDate',
                    showToday: false,
                    handler: function(picker, date) {
                        var timeIntervalPanel = this.up('button#timeIntervalPanel');
                        var endDate = timeIntervalPanel.endDate;
                        timeIntervalPanel.setDates(date, endDate);
                    }
                        }
            }
```

Comment: i want to set yesterday date as default instead of today's date in my datepicker any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In ExtJs have [Date](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.Date.html) This class defines some basic methods for handling dates.

Here is method to [add](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.Date.html#method-add) date basis of our requirement.

I have created an small demo. how is working you can see here [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/272a) hope it will help you.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Choose a future date:',
    width: 330,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datepicker',
        value:Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1),
        handler: function(picker, date) {
            // do something with the selected date
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: if my date format is ' d-M-Y H:i:s ' then how to set default time also with date can you help me out

Comment: For this format you can use [Ext.Date.format](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.Date.html#method-format)(new Date(), 'd-M-Y H:i:s') hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Put the desired date as the value.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
```

and then in your Datepicker config:

```
value: d,
```